# DLL Injector crashes

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, codeblocks

I've coded a C++ DLL Injector but it does not inject, neither does it work properly. It just crashes upon compilation in visual studio or code::blocks.

Here is my complete source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <conio.h>

//prototypes 
BOOL InjectDLL(DWORD ID, const char* dll);
DWORD GetProcessId(IN PCHAR szExeName);
BOOL SetDebugPriviledge(BOOL State);

//Main codes
int main()
{
    char dll[MAX_PATH];

    GetFullPathName("DLLTest.dll",MAX_PATH,dll,NULL);
    DWORD ID = GetProcessId("Odesk.exe");

    SetDebugPriviledge(TRUE);

    if(!InjectDLL(ID,dll))
    {
        printf("Injection Failed, Reason :%s", GetLastError());
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success!");
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;   
}

//Functions

DWORD GetProcessId(IN PCHAR szExeName)
{
    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    DWORD dwCount = 0;

    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnapshot !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe = {0};
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

        BOOL bRet = Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe);

        while(bRet)
        {
            if(!_stricmp(pe.szExeFile,szExeName))
            {
                dwCount++;
                dwRet = pe.th32ProcessID;
            }
            bRet = Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe);
        }
        if(dwCount >1)
            dwRet = 0XFFFFFFFF;
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    return dwRet;
}

BOOL SetDebugPriviledge(BOOL State)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    DWORD dwSize;
    ZeroMemory(&tp,sizeof(tp));
    tp.PrivilegeCount =1;
    if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if(!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME,&tp.Privileges[0].Luid))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    if(State)
    {
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    }else
    {
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED;
    }
    if(!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken,FALSE,&tp, 0, NULL, &dwSize))
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    return CloseHandle(hToken);
}

BOOL InjectDLL(DWORD ID, const char* dll)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    LPVOID Memory;
    LPVOID LoadLibrary;

    if(!ID)
    {
        return false;
    }   
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION,FALSE,ID);
    if(!hProcess)
    {
        printf("Error, Reason: %s",GetLastError());
    }   
    LoadLibraryA = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"),"LoadLibraryA");
    if(!LoadLibraryA)
    {
        printf("Error, Reason: %s",GetLastError());
    } 
    Memory = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess,NULL,strlen(dll)+1,MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);
    if(!Memory)
    {
        printf("Error, Reason: %s",GetLastError());
    } 
    if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess,(LPVOID)Memory, dll, strlen(dll)+1,NULL))
    {
        printf("Error, Reason: %s",GetLastError());
    }   
    if(!CreateRemoteThread(hProcess,NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibrary,(LPVOID)Memory,NULL,NULL))
    {
        printf("Error, Reason: %s",GetLastError());
    } 
    if(!CloseHandle(hProcess))
    {
        printf("Error, Reason: %s",GetLastError());
    }  
    return true; 
}
```

Can someone assist me in understanding what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it fail to compile or does it fail to debug/run?  "crashes upon compile" seems like an odd situation without an error message.

Comment: Not sure about your issue, but in a glance, you are calling [`CloseHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) twice in `SetDebugPriviledge()` which is not recommended.

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to place the errors.

I see some syntax errors (there can be more)

1:

```
LoadLibraryA = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"),"LoadLibraryA");
```

You can only assign values to variables. *LoadLibraryA* is not a variable, but its name you already have it in your program (*kernel32.dll* is loaded by default at runtime).

2: *GetLastError* returns a DWORD,

```
printf("Error, Reason: %s",GetLastError());
```

so you should replace `%s` by `%d`.

Comment: LoadLibraryA is actually probably seen as a variable to the compiler because LoadLibrary is converted by the preprocessor into LoadLibraryA when not Unicode.  Though this should be corrected, it is probably not the issue.

Comment: @David Ruhmann
It's the other way around, LoadLibraryA is also exposed by the preprocessor LoadLibrary. Anyway, the compiler will certainly complain about that syntax (this is: defining a function and assigning a value to its name).